# HttpClient alternative in Eclipse API

Tags: java, eclipse, mime, httpclient

For HTTP communications in Java, I normally use the HttpClient library.  However, my latest project utilizes the Eclipse API.  Are there features in the API that have the same capabilities as HttpClient?

As implied, this particular project requires me to use GET, PUT, and POST requests.  I also need to post multipart MIMEs where the Content-Disposition for supplied information is usually going to be "attachment."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stick with the Http client library that you are currently using.  It is what we use (via Spring Remoting) and it works just fine in that environment.

There is the [Eclipse Communication Framework](http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/), but I believe that is more oriented toward communications between Eclipse or RCP instances.  Not comms with a servlet.

Comment: Yes, there is no reason you cannot use HttpClient in an Eclipse plug-in or around other Eclipse APIs.